# How to use xsl group-by for multiple element values

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working with the below xml structure:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Report_Data>
        <Report_Entry>
            <ID>10513</ID>
            <Code>XXX</Code>
            <Payment_Date>2016-05-05-07:00</Payment_Date>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <ID>10513</ID>
            <Code>XXX</Code>
            <Payment_Date>2016-05-05-07:00</Payment_Date>
            <Amount>-25</Amount>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <ID>12076</ID>
            <Code>HHH</Code>
            <Payment_Date>2016-05-05-07:00</Payment_Date>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <ID>12166</ID>
            <Code>HHH</Code>
            <Payment_Date>2016-05-05-07:00</Payment_Date>
            <Amount>5</Amount>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <ID>12166</ID>
            <Code>HHH</Code>
            <Payment_Date>2016-05-05-07:00</Payment_Date>
            <Amount>35</Amount>
        </Report_Entry>
    </Report_Data>
```

I need to group by ID and Code only when the Code is 'XXX' and sum the Amount. So in the end, my final output should look like the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Report_Data>
        <Report_Entry>
            <ID>10513</ID>
            <Code>XXX</Code>
            <Payment_Date>2016-05-05-07:00</Payment_Date>
            <Amount>75</Amount>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <ID>12076</ID>
            <Code>HHH</Code>
            <Payment_Date>2016-05-05-07:00</Payment_Date>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <ID>12166</ID>
            <Code>HHH</Code>
            <Payment_Date>2016-05-05-07:00</Payment_Date>
            <Amount>5</Amount>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <ID>12166</ID>
            <Code>HHH</Code>
            <Payment_Date>2016-05-05-07:00</Payment_Date>
            <Amount>35</Amount>
    </Report_Entry>
```

I know how i can group by multiple elements but what I can't figure out is how to condition the group by by an element value. I don't foray into xsl very much so my knowledge is a bit lacking. I have tried using the below xsl (latest version anyways):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
        version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="Report_Data">
        <Report_Data>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Entry" group-by="concat(ID,' ',Code)">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="ID"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Code"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Payment_Date"/>
                    <Amount><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Amount[. &gt; 0] - sum(current-group()/Amount[. &lt; 0]))"/></Amount>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Report_Data>
    </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Another issue I'm having is that I don't have the sum logic quite right but that is probably a different post.

Any kind of help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: The example would be much more useful if it had at least two different groups with different IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to group by ID and Code only when the Code is 'XXX'

I think what you're trying to say is that you want to group the entries with Code 'XXX' by their ID, and leave all other entries as they are. Which would be done this way:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Report_Data">
    <Report_Data>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Entry[Code='XXX']" group-by="ID">
            <Report_Entry>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ID | Code | Payment_Date"/>
                <Amount>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Amount)"/>
                </Amount>
            </Report_Entry>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Report_Entry[not(Code='XXX')]"/>
    </Report_Data>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the `Payment_Date` value is taken from the first entry in the group. At least in theory, other entries in the same group could have other `Payment_Date` values.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much for your help! It would have helped if I slowed down to analyze the requirement a bit before rushing in.